# Ajuda para essa query

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde Pessoal, tenho essas duas tabelas que se relacionam para saber quantas vezes um usuário acessou o sistema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tenho essa query:

```
select nome_usuario, count(id_log) as qtde from logs as l left join usuario as u on l.usuario_log = u.id_usuario group by usuario_log order by qtde desc
```

Hoje ele me traz o resultado de quantas vezes o usuário acessou. E gostaria que se não encontrar registros da tabela `log` atribua zero '0' como faço isso?

Comment: você quer trazer todos os usuários independente se não tem na tabela log.

Comment: Isso, e atribuindo 0.

Comment: Deixo como dica: Quando relacionar tabelas, use exatamente o mesmo nome nas colunas id, facilita o entendimento e possibilita usar a cláusula using na query, que é bem prática...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na `SQL` da pergunta, troque [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) por [`RIGHT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp)

```
select u.id_usuario, u.nome_usuario, count(l.id_log) as qtde from logs as l 
        right join usuario as u 
           on l.usuario_log = u.id_usuario 
             group by u.id_usuario, nome_usuario 
              order by qtde desc
```

Comment: Tentei isso, mas ele não traz todos os resultados. Traz apenas um registro com valor = 0. E tem muitos outros.

Comment: Você tem como colocar exemplos de valores na sua pergunta!

Comment: Exatamente. Obrigado Amigo.

Comment: @EduardoSantos dá uma olhada assim seria melhor como edite pela ultima vez

Comment: Também funcionou. Obrigado

Comment: ou  `group by u.id_usuario, nome_usuario ` que é o correto, fiz também a edição.